# How to avoid user navigate to ajax url in laravel 5.8?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.8

I have created simple web application with laravel 5.8. 
this is my project url http://localhost/test/public/home

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'preventBackHistory']], function() {
   Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
   Route::post('generate_table.data', 'HomeController@generate_table')->name('generate_table.data');
});
```

I am calling this ajax into home.blade

```
"ajax": { 
   "url":"{!! route("generate_table.data") !!}",
   "type": "POST",
    "jsonpCallback": 'jsonCallback',
    "dataType": "jsonp"
 }
```

I haven't any issue with this ajax.it is loading data. If i navigate to http://localhost/test/public/generate_table.data?callback=jsonCallback , i am getting black screen with

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> No message

If user navigate http://localhost/test/public/generate_table.data?callback=jsonCallback How to navigate back to /home?

.env
`APP_DEBUG=false`

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot check post request by calling it via URL, you need postman or Advanced REST client, i would suggest you to download and install these apps to help you work with laravel APIs/Routes.

Comment: Thank you @Vipertecpro. I am getting records from url. In home page blade file i am calling ajax url. For security purpose i want to navigate to home screen if user visit to ajax url. The application need to return error or home page if url is not in web.php(Route) and ajax url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the user when the GET method is used.

```
// GET method will be redirected to home.
Route::get('generate_table.data', function () {
    return redirect()->to('/');
});

// The POST method will be passed to the controller.
Route::post('generate_table.data', 'HomeController@generate_table')->name('generate_table.data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your routes:

```
Route::get('generate_table.data', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Thank you @piscator. I am getting error after change route. error "Route [generate_table.data] not defined."

Comment: @tksuba Did you delete your named `POST` route?

Comment: No, I added Route::get('generate_table.data', 'HomeController@index'); 
 Route::post('generate_table.data', 'HomeController@index');